# Retrieval of data from domainevententry table based on particular event using Axonframework

Tags: java, spring-boot, axon

I am building a web application where I need to track some event like sms send, delivered, or failed.For that I want to use Axonframework . I have followed axonframework tutorial on official website and also from [this website](http://geekabyte.blogspot.in/2015/10/exploring-cqrs-architecture-with-axon.html)

but I didn't find any solution to fetch events from daomainevententry table created by Axon itself. I am using Java language, Spring framework and MySql database for complete development of my application.

Kindly tell me any good tutorial or solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using `JpaEventStorageEngine` (e.g. you have `spring-data-jpa` on your classpath and configured a JPA persistence unit using `application.properties` or `application.yml`), Axon is using the Entity `DomainEventEntry`to store the events. In your database these results in entries in the table `DOMAIN_EVENT_ENTRY` or something similiar.

To access it from Spring, you could use Spring-Data yourself. Define a Spring-Data Repository:

```
import org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa.DomainEventEntry;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface DomainEventRepository extends JpaRepository<DomainEventEntry, Long> {

}
```

By doing so you will get default access methods to query from this repository. For further customization you can write additional methods. Please consult the [documentation of Spring Data](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html) on how to do so.

Probably you are interested in querying for events for a certain aggregate:

```
List<DomainEventEntry> findByAggregateIdentifier(String aggregateIdentifier);
```

or by specific type:

```
List<DomainEventEntry> findByType(String type);
```

To explore more, just navigate the hierachy of the `DomainEventEntry`and look for interesting fields.

Hope this helps,

Simon